# Android studio "Wrote stack traces to tombstoned" when connecting to server

Tags: java, android-studio, https

I'm trying to log in to my server from my app with self-signed certificate. When I try to log in I get this error:

"Thread[6,tid=17486,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4000074d0ac6570,peer=0x147c0000,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3 "

"Wrote stack traces to tombstoned."

What could be the cause of that? I searched this error and found a few solutions but none worked.
Here is my code:

```
public class Connection extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        try {
            Connect();
        } catch (CertificateException | IOException | KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ServerDirectActivity.response = true;
            ServerDirectActivity.responseMsg = String.valueOf(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private void Connect() throws CertificateException, IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, NullPointerException {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() { @Override public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; } });
    InputStream caInput = ServerDirectActivity.getmInstanceActivity().getAssets().open("client.csr");
    Certificate ca = null;
    try{
        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    }catch (CertificateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        caInput.close();
    }

    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    URL url = new URL(serverIP);

    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    final String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes());
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
    System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
    System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseCode());
    if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200){
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            out.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(out);
    }
    ServerDirectActivity.response = true;
    ServerDirectActivity.responseMsg = String.valueOf(urlConnection.getResponseCode());


}
```

}

Comment: can you add logs?

Comment: I added some to my post

Comment: Hello, I'm getting the same error (in a different context). You said you "searched this error and found a few solutions but none worked"... what solutions did you try?